# Process data with two DataFrames using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames structured in such a way that they can be related to each other, and process them: `inputs` and `coef`.

```
import pandas as pd

inputs = [[2, 'sope',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'SD0'], 
          [2,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'QU0'], 
          [2,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'WI3'], 
          [2,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'WI2'], 
          [2, 'wix-',   0,  16,   6,  13,   0,   0.3, 'WI1'], 
          [2,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'QU1'],
          [2,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'RR0'], 
          [2, 'wix+', -13, -13,   2,   1, -62,  -0.5, 'WI0'], 
          [2,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'SS0'], 
          [2,  'cvt',  -3,   5,  17,  -2,  -9,  -0.2, 'RL0'], 
          [2,   'cv',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'LL0'], 
          [4,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'RR0'], 
          [4,  'cvt',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -1.0, 'RL0'], 
          [4, 'wix+', -18,  -2,  19,  19,   3, -64.0, 'WI0'],
          [4, 'wix-',   0, -30,  -2,  -2,  32,   0.0, 'WI1'], 
          [4,   'cv',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'LL0'], 
          [4,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'WI2'], 
          [4,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'WI3'],
          [4, 'sope', -42,   0,  29,   0,   0, -13.0, 'SD0'], 
          [4,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'QU0'],
          [4,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'SS0'], 
          [4,      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0.0, 'QU1']]

inputs = pd.DataFrame(data = inputs, columns = ['Key','Descr', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'Indicator'])
#inputs['Coef'] = inputs['Indicator'] + inputs['new'].astype(str)
 
inputs = pd.DataFrame(data = inputs, columns = ['Key','Descr','Indicator', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6'])
       
coef = [['S1',   1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S2',   1,  1.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S3',   1,  0.0,  1.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S4',   1,  0.0,  0.0, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S4.1', 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S4.2', 1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S5',   1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S6',   1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S7',   1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0], 
        ['S8',   1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0], 
        ['S8.1', 1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7], 
        ['S8.2', 1,  0.0,  0.0, 0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

coef = pd.DataFrame(data = coef, columns = ['KeyCoef','SD0', 'LL0', 'RL0', 'SS0', 'RR0', 'WI0', 'WI1', 'WI2', 'WI3', 'QU0', 'QU1'])
```

The size of the first DataFrame `inputs` can vary depending on the number of `inputs [ key ]`.

Each `inputs [key]` stores a group of data, in my case I only have `inputs [ key ] = [2, 4];` also in this DataFrame I have an `inputs [ Indicator ]`, which is the way to relate the data of this DataFrame with the second one.

The second DataFrame will always have the same size and houses the coefficients that indicate how to process the data from the first DataFrame.

The logic of how to do it I have programmed it in Excel with functions like `vlookup`, but I am not very clear how to do it using Pandas, I have tried with `.merge` but I have not achieved much so far. [See attached excel.](https://utpl-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/davillarreal1_utpl_edu_ec/EXK_0N-AtxJGuXsKXadzmfgBO_4xrKo6nsFXxEvwqdJgzw?e=VAGiuX)

I would be very grateful if you can help me with the idea and your suggestions, if there is any doubt, I am pending. Greetings.

Comment: Good question but IMO a bit complicated to understand :) Maybe if you minimalize it you can attract more helpers.

Comment: Yes I know @emremrah, in fact that data that is there are previously processed data with code, only that this part is the one that I have not been able to solve it, that is why I attached an Excel where the logical process is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. The Excel file you linked has different columns from the dataframes you show us here.

Still, to replicate a vlookup in Excel, you can do merge your two dataframes using the following:

```
coef.T.reset_index().merge(inputs, left_on='index', right_on='Indicator')
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to explain the process: first I look for each header of the DataFrame 'coef', the corresponding one in the DataFrame 'Inputs', for the 'C1' column, and is multiplied by the intersected value of the DataFrame 'coef', this I do with all The headers of 'Coef', and then the sumo. I repeat this procedure for 'C2', .. 'C6'. And down, I just have to change the coefficients 'coef'. As in the spreadsheet. @vtasca